# Add AzureAD users to AzureAD group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have an AzureAD group. I need to ~200k users into this group. Is there a powershell command that I could use in order to add n number of users into AzureAD group. Please let me know.

Comment: You can use [`add-azureadgroupmember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) from the AzureAD Module.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add multiple member to a single group:

Run the `Connect-AzureAD` command to log in to your Azure account.

```
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "carl"} 
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser | select userprincipalname,objectid | where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like 'ca*'} 
$users = $useradd.objectid

 foreach($user in $users){ 

 Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user 
}
```

[image]